# Получение значения тега title

Tags: php

Здравствуйте. Подскажите пожалуйста, вот стоит задача получить значение тега title с другого сайта, сайт заранее не известен, он может быть абсолютно любым.
Как я это сейчас делаю

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$tag = 'title';
@$dom->loadHTML(@file_get_contents('http://site.com/'));

if ($dom->getElementsByTagName($tag)->length > 0)
    $title = $dom->getElementsByTagName($tag)->item(0)->textContent;
else
    $title = '';
```

Но сайты на которых кодировка windows-1251 отдают мне title в таком виде

```
Site - Ðåêëàìíîå àãåíòñòâî. Ýôôåêòèâíàÿ ðàñêðóòêà ñàéòîâ
```

Пробовал использовать функции mb_convert_encoding() и iconv() с разными параметрами, но ни одна из них не дала нужного результата. Подскажите пожалуйста как можно получить читабельный title где кодировка windows-1251

Comment: Покажите, как вы использовали mb_convert_encoding() или iconv() в этом коде.

Comment: После того как получал значение в переменную title создавал ещё одну переменную в которую вносил результат выполнения этих функций, а всё что я там менял, это из какой кодировки в какую делать процесс

Comment: Думаю, что вам надо перекодировать в `UTF-8` результат работы функции `file_get_contents()` и только потом загружать данные в `DOMDocument`.

Answer (score 1):

```
$str='Ðåêëàìíîå àãåíòñòâî. Ýôôåêòèâíàÿ ðàñêðóòêà ñàéòîâ';

$str = iconv('utf-8', 'cp1252', $str);
$str = iconv('cp1251', 'utf-8', $str);

echo  $str;

//Рекламное агентство. Эффективная раскрутка сайтов
```

Тест online: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/285d0149220b35b140504c32d7ec6eb26f7a9c54